# Connected app - packaging vs subscriber org and access token validity

Tags: connected-apps, certificates, packaging

I had a brief question about how certificates work in a ConnectedApp within a packaging org.

To give context, we have a packaging org that contains a single ConnectedApp. This ConnectedApp uses the JWT Authorization flow + certificate combination. When testing this authorization, I was met with a peculiar scenario.

To test what would happen by updating the certificate in the ConnectedApp in the packing org, I followed these steps:

```
1. Customer installs package containing the connected app in their org
2. We use the private key for that org and get back the access token
3. I create a new private key + cert and create a new package version w/ updated ConnectedApp
4. Using the NEW private key, I’m able to STILL grab an access code from the org that has it installed.
5. Using the OLD private key, I’m not able to retrieve it anymore.
```

The catch is, I *never* installed the updated package version. It's as if the ConnectedApp updated on its own in all the orgs that had it installed? Am I going crazy - or is this functionality provided out-of-the-box ... or did I maybe do something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Connected App *lives* in **your** org. The subscriber's installed version is just a shadow of the original. Any changes you make to it will affect all orgs that use that Connected App. This is one of the reasons why packaging a Connected App is no longer necessary, because it can connect to any org without installing it at all (try this on a fresh Scratch Org or Developer Org to see how this works). If you want a per-app-type thing, you'll need to create the Connected App in the subscriber org, then have them provide the client Id, secret, etc.

Comment: Gotcha. I appreciate your insight. For clarification sake, you're saying that the ConnectedApp propagates the updates to the orgs that it's installed in without the need to use a packaging org.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor no, the Connected App used is the one from your org. The shadow copy is used only for permissions/blocking.  A Connected App is many to prove that an app is yours and not someone else imitating you. If your subscriber could modify this, they could impersonate your app maliciously.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thank you for your clarification.